# How to force pymodis python script to bypass internet explorer proxy

Tags: python, proxy, pymodis

I am trying to use the pymodis (www.pymodis.org/index.html) python library to download modis data but I get stopped by my internet explorer proxy. I can deactivate it manually and it works fine but I would like to know if there is a way to modify the python script so that I don't have to do this everytime I need to download something.

The script for which I get an error is downmodis (https://github.com/lucadelu/pyModis/blob/master/pymodis/downmodis.py)

I get the following error:

```
raise Exception("There are some troubles with the server. "
```

Exception: There are some troubles with the server. The directory seems to be em
pty

This error comes from line 343

I also found this link (https://www.decalage.info/en/python/urllib2noproxy) which I feel might be usefull but I can't seem to get this solution to work (see line 253 from downmodis.py)